# Convert GSAP animation to pure SVG (SMIL)

Tags: javascript, svg, gsap

Is it possible to export or convert a GSAP SVG animation into pure SVG (SMIL)?

For example taking this gsap svg: https://codepen.io/chrisgannon/pen/QjvzYo

```
    var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",
  select = function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s);
  },
  selectAl . . .etc
```

and converting it to pure SVG?

I'm aware of the SMIL support limitations (although personally I have not experienced them on Safari or Chrome).  The reason I need it to be SMIL is JS is not supported in email clients where I need the animation to appear.

Many thanks

Comment: Do you mean by using SMIL? It's not very well supported, so not sure that would be the best plan. Most SVG animations are done using JS.

Comment: Yes thanks - needs to be with SMIL as I need to use the SVG in html email where JS can't be used and CSS animations don't really work.  I'll update the question to reflect need to be in SMIL